# Getting Error While Trying to add entry OpenLDAP on Fedora 19

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to add the following entries to LDAP.

```
dn: dc=testdomain,dc=in
dc: testdomain
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain

dn: ou=People,dc=testdomain,dc=in
ou: People
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: ou=Group,dc=testdomain,dc=in
ou: Group
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

I'm getting the error:

```
adding new entry "dc=testdomain,dc=in"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with organizationalUnit. See the DN of the entry it's complaining about. Maybe it doesn't like 'objectClass: domain', or maybe you should just omit the whole entry as it is probably the rootDSE.

Comment: Agreed, it is `objectClass: domain` that is causing the problem. (Edited question) but omitting it doesn't solve the problem. I am now getting the following error: `Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "ou=People,dc=geminisolutions,dc=in"
ldap_add: No such object (32)`

Comment: The idea is to remove the non-existent objectClass 'domain', not the entire entry. You need that, to be the parent of the second one. Or else load a schema containing 'domain'.